# looking for something like SQL LIKE Operator

Tags: php

i am looking for same code to search things in my table colmon.
i dont want its search something "like" the input search.
i want it to search the exactly Value in the table.

if user search "the walking dead season 3 episode 1"
its search exactly  "the walking dead season 3 episode 1" in the "moviename" row..
and dont show me the all results look like thats..

**my code now is :**

```
<?php
function connect($host,$username,$database,$password){
 $to_connect = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die ("UNFinded ".$username. " DB !");
 $db = mysql_select_db($database, $to_connect) or die (mysql_error());
 return $db;
}
connect("localhost","idevice2_ariel","idevice2_ariel","ariel123456");


if (!isset($_POST['submit_form'])) {
    echo '<form name="search_form1" method="POST" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="search_name" value="search movie name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_form" />
</form>';
} else {
       $search_name = $_POST['search_name'];
       $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM members where `moviename` = $search_name");
       $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
       $fname = $row['moviename'];
       $lname = $row['links'];
       print '<a href="'.$row['links'].'">'.$row['moviename'].'</a><br />';

}

}
?>
```

thanks you! ariel.

Comment: Use the equal sign? `moviename = ...` Sidenote: it would be reeally frustrating for a user..Oh, and you're wide open to sql injections

Comment: `moviename = 'the walking dead season 3 episode 1'`

Comment: i need to use one "="? or two? i Beginner.. thank you

Comment: Sql Injection make the party

Comment: Lesson #1: go read the documentation (and use google). You would have seen in a few minutes the right syntax

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions is [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit_form'])) {
    echo '<form name="search_form1" method="POST" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="search_name" value="search movie name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_form" />
</form>';
} else {
       $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
       $search_name = $_POST['search_name'];
       $query = $mysqli->prepare("Select * from members where moviename = ? OR links = ?");
       $query->bindParam('ss',$search_name,$search_name);
       $query->execute();
       $query->bind_result($link,$movieName);
       while($query->fetch()) {
           echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$movieName.'</a><br />';    
       }
       $query->close();

}
?>
```

Consider using prepared statements.

Comment: This is still open to sql injections, and has an error in the query (you didn't even quoted the string, at least OP did that). If you're gonna theach something, do that right all the way

Comment: Sorry, got lazy on initial answer.